# Как отобразить кнопку поверх остальных элементов или поверх tabPage или поверх tabControl?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как отобразить кнопку поверх остальных элементов или поверх tabPage или поверх tabControl?

```
_tabPages.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage());
            _tabPages[countOfGraphs - 1].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
            _tabPages[countOfGraphs - 1].Name = "_tabPages" + countOfGraphs;
            _tabPages[countOfGraphs - 1].Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
            _tabPages[countOfGraphs - 1].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(930, 440);
            _tabPages[countOfGraphs - 1].TabIndex = countOfGraphs;
            _tabPages[countOfGraphs - 1].Text = "File_" + countOfGraphs+"    ";
            _tabPages[countOfGraphs - 1].SendToBack();
            _tabPages[countOfGraphs - 1].UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            _tabPages[countOfGraphs - 1].Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
          | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
          | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            tabControl2.Controls.Add(_tabPages[countOfGraphs - 1]);


            buttonX.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Button());
            //this.buttonCut.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            buttonX[countOfGraphs - 1].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, -20);
            buttonX[countOfGraphs - 1].Name = "buttonX";
            buttonX[countOfGraphs - 1].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 24);
            buttonX[countOfGraphs - 1].TabIndex = 8;
            buttonX[countOfGraphs - 1].Text = "><";
            buttonX[countOfGraphs - 1].BringToFront();
            buttonX[countOfGraphs - 1].Show();
            buttonX[countOfGraphs - 1].Visible = true;
            buttonX[countOfGraphs - 1].BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
            buttonX[countOfGraphs - 1].UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            //buttonX[countOfGraphs - 1].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonCut_Click);
            _tabPages[countOfGraphs - 1].Controls.Add(buttonX[countOfGraphs - 1]);
```

Comment: кнопка должна относиться к TabPage, TabControl или форме? в котором из указанных контейнеров ее надо разместить и отобразить поверх других?

Comment: @rdorn поверх tabpages

Answer (score 1):

докс.майкрософт.ком подсказывает:

> To layer controls programmatically
> Use the BringToFront and SendToBack methods to manipulate the z-order of the controls.
>
> For example, if a TextBox control, txtFirstName, is underneath another control and you want to have it on top, use the following code:

```
txtFirstName.BringToFront();
```